# MQTT on_publish gives no feedback and connection gets lost every 90 seconds despite keepalive=930

Tags: python, logging, raspberry-pi, mqtt, publish

I am using paho-mqtt in my python script and the values of my temperature sensor are published every 15 minutes as they should, so this works fine. But on closer consideration of my logfile the MQTT connection gets lost approx. every 90 seconds although my keepalive value is at 930 (15 minutes and 30 seconds). The entries in my logfile deliver:

```
INFO:root:Unexpected disconnection. Reason: Connection Refused: unacceptable protocol version.
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be? Cheers

This is my script:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import Adafruit_DHT
import time
import ssl
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='/home/pi/Documents/mqtt.log', encoding='utf-8')

# Set up DHT22 sensor
dht_sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
dht_pin = 4  # GPIO pin number the sensor is connected to

username = 'master:mqttuser_karlsruhe'
secret = 'ifYsftrjtzktzkfDSc'
host = '192.168.0.52'
port = 8883
clientID = 'raspi_ka'
assetID = '3ndhrtjtz55rrGa'


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    logging.info("Connected with result code "+str(rc))


def on_publish(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    logging.info(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        print("Unexpected disconnection.")
        logging.info(f"Unexpected disconnection. Reason: {mqtt.connack_string(rc)}")


def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print("log: ", buf)
    logging.info("log: ", buf)


mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(clientID)
mqtt_client.username_pw_set(username, password=secret)
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
mqtt_client.tls_set_context(context)
mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
mqtt_client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
mqtt_client.on_publish = on_publish
mqtt_client.on_log = on_log
mqtt_client.connect(host, port=port, keepalive=930)
mqtt_client.loop_start()

# Continuously read and send temperature values
while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(dht_sensor, dht_pin)
    if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
        mqtt_client.publish(f"master/{clientID}/writeattributevalue/temperature/{assetID}", temperature)
        mqtt_client.publish(f"master/{clientID}/writeattributevalue/humidity/{assetID}", humidity)
    else:
        print("Failed to read temperature sensor data")
    print(temperature)
    print("")
    time.sleep(900)

# Disconnect MQTT client
mqtt_client.disconnect()
mqtt_client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: One problem per question please

Comment: Okay, I changed my question therefore

Comment: What broker are you using and how is it configured when listening on port 8883?

Comment: The IoT platform OpenRemote is the broker. I set it up locally on localhost. What do you mean by 'how is it configured'? :)

Comment: I mean what is the broker expecting on port 8883, MQTT, MQTT with TLS, MQTT over Websockets, MQTT over Secure WebSockets? Given the default native MQTT port 1883 and 8883 tends to be used for MQTT with TLS are you sure you are 1) using the right port, 2) configuring the client correctly to talk to the broker on that port.

Comment: I am not 100 % sure, MQTT is pretty new for me. I would say he is expecting MQTT with TLS. But maybe this instruction page, which gave me orientation, tells more: https://github.com/openremote/openremote/wiki/Tutorial:-Connect-your-MQTT-Client . Yes the port is right and my values arrive every 15 minutes at the platform, so this works actually fine.